# Error with pointers to member variables as parameters; why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointer-to-member

Why do I keep on getting the following error in this code in Visual C++ 2010, and how do I fix it while maintaining the type inference capability for the member variable?

> error C2825: `'Foo<T>::value_type':` must be a class or namespace when followed by `'::'`

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;

    template<class M>
    void foo(M value_type::*member) const;   // error
};
struct S { typedef int value_type; };

int main() { Foo<S> s; }
```

Comment: What's the parameter for `foo` supposed to be (in words)?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: lol oops... either I made a stupid mistake in the original code, or I reduced the test case wrong... let me find the problem and I'll post an update, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please elaborate more what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry everyone -- I misinterpreted what was happening. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877464/error-with-pointers-to-member-variables-as-parameters-why#comment15804094_11877528) on Nawaz's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parameter `T` turns out to be type `S`, therefore `value_type` turns out to be `int` (the nested-type in `S`). So how can you write `value_type::*member`? Note that it turns out to be `int::*member` which doesn't make sense. `int` is not a class type.

I think you meant `T::*member` instead of `value_type::*member`.

Comment: Oh fudge, either I made a stupid mistake in the original code, or I reduced the test case incorrectly... let me fix it; +1 thanks...

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I figured it out -- this was a red herring. The actual problem was that I had a member function (with this weird parameter) and its template instantiation was eager instead of lazy (not sure if it's a bug or a feature, since the container was also a template...), so when I was chaining a couple of method calls, I thought the error was due to the second one, not the first one! The first one definitely had `value_type = int`, but the second one had `value_type = pair<int, int>`. That makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

value_type is not a member of structure S.
Its just a typedef so you cant access it as you are doing.